# SELECT in WHERE LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have 2 tables country_codes and Database.
I need to retrive all columns from the database if the country code exist on the table country codes. For example, I have 123 on my country codes table, I need
to select all columns if the Phone_Number Column's first 3 digit is 123. So I will select the number 1234567.

Table Name : Country_Codes

```
+---------------+
|Country_Code   |
+---------------+
|   123         |
|   456         |
|   556         |
|   231         |
+---------------+
```

Table Name : Database

```
+---------------+--------+
|Phone_Number   | Used   |
+---------------+--------+
|   1234567     |  No    |
|   4568823     |  No    |
|   5562143     |  No    |
|   5582143     |  No    |
|   2319042     |  No    |
+---------------+--------+
```

The Result that I want is

Table Name : Database

```
+---------------+--------+
|Phone_Number   | Used   |
+---------------+--------+
|   1234567     |  No    |
|   4568823     |  No    |
|   5562143     |  No    |
|   2319042     |  No    |
+---------------+--------+
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT * FROM database 
WHERE database.phone_number LIKE (SELECT country_code FROM country_codes);
```

But I keep on getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Before post the solution, some considerations:

1. Don't call a table with name `DATABASE`
2. You can normalized better your structure, you can add a foreign key in the DATABASE table about country_code

Try this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM database d
JOIN Country_Codes cc
    ON cc.Country_Code like concat(d.Phone_Number, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use exists and left keywords and get the result : 

CREATE TABLE #Country_Codes(Country_Code VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Country_Codes(Country_Code)
SELECT 123 UNION ALL
SELECT 456 UNION ALL
SELECT 556 UNION ALL
SELECT 231 

CREATE TABLE #Country_Database(Phone_Number VARCHAR(100), Used VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Country_Database(Phone_Number , Used)
SELECT '1234567','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '4568823','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '5562143','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '5582143','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '2319042','No' 

SELECT Phone_Number,Used
FROM #Country_Database
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Country_Codes WHERE Country_Code =     
LEFT(Phone_Number,3))
```